# How to add two variables in Cloudformation Fn::Sub in UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am able to add 1 variable but unable to add second, I am a sys admin, and not that much knowledgeable about YAML

```
UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub  
       - |+  
        #!/bin/bash -xe  
        NEW_HOSTNAME=${test}  
       - test:   
             Fn::FindInMap: [Regions, !Ref "AWS::Region", Name]
```

I would like to add another FindInMap variable after test, but I am unable to.

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow! I just edited that code, now I cannot accept my own answer unit 4 hours. I did mark it as resolved but its not accepting since yesterday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub
    - |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      foo=${foo}
      baz=${baz}
    - foo: !FindInMap [FooMap, Foo, Value]
      baz: !FindInMap [FooMap, Baz, Value]
```

It could also be formatted as:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub
    - |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      foo=${foo}
      baz=${baz}
    - {
        foo: !FindInMap [FooMap, Foo, Value],
        baz: !FindInMap [FooMap, Baz, Value]
      }
```

See also docs for the [`Fn::FindInMap`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html) function.

Note that I removed the `|+` - which is a YAML feature and says to keep the trailing newlines. It isn't really required here.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserData: 
              Fn::Base64: !Sub
               - |
                  #!/bin/bash
                  NEW_HOSTNAME=${hostName}
               -  {
                  share: !FindInMap [Regions, !Ref "AWS::Region", SHARE],
                  hostName: !Join ["", [!Ref Name, !FindInMap [Regions, 
                                                         !Ref"AWS::Region",USERDATA] ] ]
                  }
```