# AWS CloudFormation UserData EC2 Environment Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm working on an infrastructure with CloudFormation.
That is my own infrastructure code shown below .

```yaml
 AWSRegionArch2AMI:
     us-east-1:
       HVM64: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
       HVMG2: ami-0a584ac55a7631c0c
 ...
 ..
 .

 Resources:
 EC2Instance:
 Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
 Properties:
 InstanceType:
    Ref: InstanceType
  SecurityGroups:
  - Ref: InstanceSecurityGroup
  KeyName:
    Ref: KeyName
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash
      export MY_AMI_NAME=${ !GetAtt AWSRegionArch2AMI.us-east-1.HVM64 }

      echo $MY_AMI_NAME > $HOME/user_data.txt
```

I want to set the variable to the user_data file but it is empty, How I can get the environment variable to inside my user data field and use it my own application side How I can do it.

Please help !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```yaml
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub
    - |
      #!/bin/bash
      MY_AMI_NAME=${image_id}
      echo $MY_AMI_NAME > $HOME/user_data.txt
    - image_id: !GetAtt AWSRegionArch2AMI.us-east-1.HVM64
```

Explanation:

- Use of `export` in Bash is to make variables available to subshells - "environment variables". You don't need it there.
- See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) for proper use of the `!Sub` function.
- See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571665/3787051) related Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks bro! I've found it from docs at before already , Thank you so much it works !